# Gnuplot filledcurves for closed lines doesn't work properly

Tags: gnuplot, fill

I have a problem with gnuplot filled curves. I calculated some data to draw a picture using this code:

```
plot 'cont.dat' u 1:2 w filledcurves closed lc rgb "#ADFF2F"  title "DF"
'cont2.dat' u 1:2 w filledcurve lc rgb "#CD5C5C" title "DA",\
'cont3.dat' u 1:2 w filledcurve lc rgb "#4682B4" title "(DF+DA)/2",\
'cont3.dat' u 1:2 w l lw 3 lc rgb "#4682B4" notitle ,\
'cont.dat' u 1:2 w l lw 3 lc rgb "#ADFF2F" notitle,\
'cont2.dat' u 1:2 w l lw 3 lc rgb "#CD5C5C" notitle
```

And everything was fine with this data:

[image]

But when I calculated another case. Trying to draw using the same code I received the following wrong result:

[image]

How could I change my code to fill the areas fully? I don't need this transparent 'holes'.

UPD:Here you can find data of green area which have been plotted wrong:
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzheur2mx9h902f/cont.dat?dl=0
It doesn't matter either you plot three curves ore just one the result for each curve is the same.

I used GNUplot 4.6 for Windows

Comment: Please show the data for *one* wrong curve so that we can try to reproduce this. And which gnuplot version do you use?

Comment: The problem is, that the file you want to plot has different data blocks (parts separated by a new line). Those are treated as separate curves, each and you don't have a single filled area. You see this, when plotting you data with `plot for [i=0:4] 'cont.dat' using 1:2 every :::i::i with lines lw 3`. Unfortunately, removing those new lines doesn't fix this, because the ordering of the lines isn't like you need it to be. However, I don't know if something went wrong when you created the contour with gnuplot so that you got several contour segments instead of a single one.

Comment: I tried remove empty lines from input data and then sorted it by 1st column. So I suppose that now GNUplot doesn't response the data like separate curves. Unfortunately, now my plot looks like this[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nv8qts0bw645h7/Small_for_paper.png?dl=0).
I tried to find solution. But in fact I'm not sure if the problem actually caused by filling routine or by the methof of calculating curves from previous data.

Comment: As I told you, the problem is that the calculation of the curves from your previous data is faulty, because it creates several curves instead of a single one. For plotting lines this is fine, but not for filling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, **one** of the problems in your data is that it is separated into blocks. But solving this issue is not enough. Let us focus in the figure below:

[image: filled curves]

The figure on top corresponds to your original data. I plotted each data-block with different colors. If we remove the white spaces, the middle/blue figure is obtained, so the issue is not resolved yet.

If you look into the data, the first column of each data-block is sorted in the direction of the arrows (top figure), but the data-blocks are sorted in the opposite direction: **They are disconnected!**

So, the data-blocks should be sorted as **0-4-3-2-1** (or any cyclic order, such as 3-2-1-0-4). The white spaces should also be removed. Once you do this, the bottom/red figure is obtained.

This is part of the code I used to draw the picture:

```
plot for [i=0:4] 'cont_original.dat' u 1:2 every :::i::i w filledc t 'original block '.i,\
     'cont_nospaces.dat' u 1:($2-0.2) w filledc t 'original without spaces',\
     'cont_ordered.dat'  u 1:($2-0.4) w filledc t 'ordered'
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it look exactly how I need. It's good lesson for me to analyse input data.